# php - Изменить текст после выполнения условия

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Цель такая: нужно чтобы после выполнения условия изменялась указанная строчка текста

```
Текстовое поле которое должно изменяться //например <p id="p1">Привет мир!</p>

<?php 
$_POST['name'] = trim($_POST['name']); 
$_POST['pass'] = trim($_POST['pass']);
if(empty($_POST['name'])) exit('Текст который должен появиться 1'); 
if(empty($_POST['pass'])) exit('Текст который должен появиться 2'); 
...
...
...
echo "<HTML><HEAD> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'> 
</HEAD></HTML>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Я верю... нет, я знаю, что на этом сайте есть люди, способные понять, чего хочет автор вопроса.

Comment: Что не понятного? Я объясню, задавай)

Comment: 1. При чем тут JavaScript? (в метке) 2. В чем вы видите проблему со своим кодом (что он делает не так или не делает) ? 3. Какой результат вы ожидали получить от этого кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите, уточню.
Страница отрисовывается полностью? Или вы хотите асинхронно изменить на ней один элемент?

Если полностью, то не городите огород, сохраните 'Текст который должен появиться 1' в переменную **$rtext1** и вставьте в нужное место.

Если требуется асинхронно обрабатывать ответ сервера, то это ajax. Вариантов реализации несколько. Я бы рекомендовал самый простой - добавить jquery и пользовать **$.post({....**

Если хотите, напишу подробнее, но сообщите сначала, правильно ли я вас понял.

upd

```
<?php 
    $_POST['name'] = trim($_POST['name']); 
    $_POST['pass'] = trim($_POST['pass']);
    if(empty($_POST['name'])) $name_message='Текст который должен появиться 1'; 
    if(empty($_POST['pass'])) $pass_message='Текст который должен появиться 2'; 
    $php_self=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    echo "<HTML><HEAD> 
    <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; $php_self'> 
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <p id='p1'>$name_message</p>
        <p id='p2'>$pass_message</p>
    </body>
    </HTML>"; 
?>
```

В общем если кавычки после экхо двойные, то переменные можно просто втыкать в текст. Массивов типа POST это не касается

Comment: В моем случаем страница отрисовывается полностью.
Хотелось бы узнать как сделать все через переменную)
Хотелось бы следующее: Чтобы была одна строка и она изменялась в зависимости от условия (  т.е. exit(изменить строку на текст 1)  )

Comment: В этом я несилен)
Эти строчки:
     <p id="p1">$name_message</p> 
     <p id="p2">$pass_message</p>

Пишутся как текст

Comment: После экхо кавычки двойные поставьте(") внутри одинарные (')

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня массив post. Хотелось бы все это  реализовать чтобы текст изменялся в самом верху (в шапке). Если конечно такое возможно)

Comment: Шапка в смысле название вкладки? Кстати, если кавычки одинарные можно так: echo 'text html <p id="p1">'.$name_message.'</p> html text'; То есть одинарные кавычки нужно резать, чтобы вставить переменную.

Comment: Вообще ничего не получилось, что то я не то делаю, но все равно спасибо за помощь) Потом как то сам разберусь, уже достаточно поздно пойду спать)

Comment: В шапке т.е. вверху страницу

Comment: Ну так куда поставите переменную с текстом, там он и отобразится. Хоть в шапке, хоть в подвале. Вот на самом деле будет проще, если вы целиком или минимизированный скрипт свой пришлёте, я его поправлю.